# How can convert affine to Jacobian coordinates?

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, prime-numbers

I have a point in affine coordinates: $(x,y)$.

What should I do when I want to convert to $(X,Y,Z)$ in Jacobian coordinates? 
I need it for calculating ECC in a prime field.

Answer (score 10):

When you go from Affine to Jacobian, $X$ and $Y$ stay the same, and $Z$ is equal to $1$

Affine -> Jacobian:

$(X',Y',Z') = (X,Y,1)$

Jacobian -> Affine:

$(X',Y') = (\frac{X}{Z^2}, \frac{Y}{Z^3} )$

Comment: Note that the division in the Jacobian -> Affine transformation is based on the [Modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse). You can't just use the integer division operation offered by common programming languages.

Comment: and what if $Z=0$?

Comment: Z = 0 means something went wrong in your algorithm. It should never occur if you add or multiply points on the curve.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a point $(x,y)$ to get its Jacobian coordinates $(X,Y,Z)$, take a $\lambda \in K^*$ and $(X,Y,Z) = (x\lambda^2, y\lambda^3, \lambda)$. The special/identity point is mapped to $(1,1,0)$.

Where $K$ is the field (of the definition of the Elliptic curve)